# How do I create a lambda expression using return value from another lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees, linq-expressions

**Neither the question nor the answer is the same as the question "Convert Linq expression “obj => obj.Prop” into “parent => parent.obj.Prop”".**  The only duplicate I've found on here lately is the number of duplicate mods with control issues.

I'm attempting to make a extension method for Entity Framework that will add a "Contains" call on a field if the given value is not null or whitespace.  It's out of pure laziness of not wanting all the if statement checks for null or whitespace.

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
var qry = MyDb.Redacteds.OrderBy(a=>a.RedactedDate);

qry = qry.WhereContains(a => a.RedactedName, txtRedactedName.Text);
```

I've come up with this, but obviously the Invoke causes an issue with EF.  What's the trick to using the result of a lambda when building an expression?

```
// create
// ent => exp(ent).Contains(s)
public static IQueryable<T> WhereContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, string>> exp, string s)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        s = s.Trim();
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "ent");;
        var call = Expression.Invoke(exp, param); // <-= HERE
        var body = Expression.Call(call, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(s));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        qry = qry.Where(lambda);
    }
    return qry;
}
```

If it was simply a delegate instead of a lambda, the return could simple be:

```
ent => exp(ent).Contains(s)
```

That's what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to grab the parameter off the lambda and use the body as the expression.  You aren't using it as a lambda at all - you are picking the expression tree and parameters out of the lambda.

```
    // create
    // ent => exp(ent).Contains(s)
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, string>> exp, string s)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        {
            s = s.Trim();

            //HERE GRAB THE PARAMETER
            var param = exp.Parameters[0];

            //HERE JUST USE EXP.BODY
            var body = Expression.Call(exp.Body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(s));

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
            qry = qry.Where(lambda);
        }
        return qry;
    }
```